# What the correct way to set up a React JSON database that all users can update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React. Im trying to have a public json that everyone can update from a form. I know how to use the api requests to fill out the json file.
But what is the correct method of setting up a globally accessible json api inside my application.
Say it adds to a list of favorite puppies. Users can see everything everyone adds to the list.

Comment: You will need to have a backend server for this

Comment: Hey there, this question is probably to broad for Stackoverflow since you are basically asking 'how do I build a backend.' There are a lot of different 'right' ways to do this. I recommend taking an intro course on Backend software development

Comment: The answer was npx install -g json-server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.